# TypeError: undefined is not a function - Node.js & MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For some reason, functions called on my cursor object are not found. 
Here's my code:

```
var db = req.db;
var goalscollection = db.get('goalscollection');
var collection = db.get('hoursburnedcollection');

var cursor = collection.find({goal: selectedgoal}, console.log);  
// the line above prints the correct cursor object

var doc = cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : null;  //line 51
// the line above gives an error
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at /Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/routes/index.js:51:27
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
at router (/Users/chrispark/Projects/LifeTool/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure your `collection` is not undefined

Comment: my collection is not undefined. the cursor is correct (i.e. contains the right documents)

Answer (score 1):

From where `myCursor` comes?

Use `cursor` instead of `myCursor`:

```
var doc = cursor.hasNext() ? cursor.next() : null;  //line 51
```

Comment: sorry, that's what i meant. even with the change, same error.

Comment: Which version of mongodb library you are using ?

Comment: The version i'm using is 2.0.33

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a callback function to `find`, the cursor will only be provided to the callback and not returned.  So remove the `console.log` parameter and you'll get the cursor.

Also, `next` doesn't return the next doc, it provides back to the caller via an async callback.

```
var cursor = collection.find({goal: selectedgoal});
if (cursor.hasNext()) {
    cursor.next(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });
}
```

Comment: This gives the same error (undefined is not a function) on cursor.hasNext(). It seems like its having trouble recognizing mongodb functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the error line number ?

I would say the error is comming from those lines :

```
var goalscollection = db.get('goalscollection');
var collection = db.get('hoursburnedcollection');
```

I can't find any method `get` in driver API.
It should be `db.collection()` :

```
var goalscollection = db.collection('goalscollection');
var collection = db.collection('hoursburnedcollection');
```